# How do I intercept Windows key under Windows 7?

Tags: c++, windows-7, keyboard-hook

Greetings,

I've implemented a low-level keyboard hook as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188951.aspx). This works fine under WinXP.
Problem is, under Windows 7 the left and right windows keys are no longer intercepted.

Any suggestions as to how to recapture these keys under Windows 7 greatly appreciated!

Cheers,

Rony

Comment: The Windows key by itself, or are you trying to register a global hotkey?  If the latter, you can simply call `RegisterHotKey`.  Note, however, that all hotkeys using the Windows key are reserved for use by Windows, so your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 4):

I have built a library because normal hooking was not working for me in a number of cases, so I've built a c library to communicate with filter drivers under the hood to do the work of device input interception. Here's a sample of how to capture the Windows key using this library:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <interception.h>
#include "utils.h" // for process priority control

const InterceptionKeyStroke windows_key_down = {91, INTERCEPTION_KEY_E0 | INTERCEPTION_KEY_DOWN};
const InterceptionKeyStroke windows_key_up = {91, INTERCEPTION_KEY_E0 | INTERCEPTION_KEY_UP};

bool operator == (const InterceptionKeyStroke &left, const InterceptionKeyStroke &right)
{
    return left.code == right.code && left.state == right.state;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    InterceptionContext context;
    InterceptionDevice device;
    InterceptionStroke stroke;

    raise_process_priority();

    context = interception_create_context();

    interception_set_filter(context, interception_is_keyboard, INTERCEPTION_FILTER_KEY_ALL);

    while(interception_receive(context, device = interception_wait(context), &stroke, 1) > 0)
    {
        InterceptionKeyStroke &keystroke = *(InterceptionKeyStroke *) &stroke;

        if(keystroke == windows_key_down)
            cout << "Windows Key Down" << endl;

        if(keystroke == windows_key_up)
            cout << "Windows Key Up" << endl;

        interception_send(context, device, &stroke, 1);
    }

    interception_destroy_context(context);

    return 0;
}
```

The sample captures the key and send it back to the operating system, but you can do other things instead.

You can check more docs at http://oblita.com/Interception.

Comment: I have the device vid and pid for some touch screens I want to hook/intercept.  Can your interception library+driver be used to catch those?  Or is it limited to mice and keyboards?

Comment: @phyatt currently it's limited to mice and keyboard sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Win Kernel SDK for Windows 7 and program a "driver" that do hook this too.

Comment: Thank, I'll look this up.
I was hoping there's a less painful solution, though...